# What's an adjective to describe the type of writing found in essays?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

You might say that writing found in literature is *literary*; language like that found in poetry is *poetic*.

What do you call writing found in essays, or writing like that found in essays?
(Not considering *prosaic*, to head off certain humorous tangents.)

Is there a word or short phrase better than *essayistic*?

---

In addition to pieces of writing originating from or destined for an academic group, here are a couple of items that appear to fall into the same category:

[Errol Morris's blog in the *New York Times*](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/category/errol-morris/)

[One of many 'essays' by Paul Graham: Makers/Managers Schedules](http://www.paulgraham.com/makersschedule.html)

Also see [Paul Graham: The Age of the Essay](http://www.paulgraham.com/essay.html)

Comment: *Anything* would be better than *essayistic*!

Comment: So far, I'm liking both 'scholarly' and 'expository.'  'Scholarly' seems to apply to a more restricted class within this kind of writing, but in much the same way that "literary" applies within fiction writing.

Comment: I think of essays as *persuasive* writing. It seems like one of the big differences between an *essay* and an *article* is that the essayist is building an argument.

Comment: Why don't you want to consider *prosaic*? That's actually the first word that springs to mind for me.

Comment: @gnovice -- *prosaic* is too ambiguous ; synonyms [from wordnik] include : boring · commonplace · dull · prosy · unimaginative · uninteresting · unpoetical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best term I've come across is *discursive* writing. *Discursive* means *relating to a [discourse](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/discourse)*, which in turn is defined as

> a speech or piece of writing about a particular, usually serious, subject.

Comment: .. hmm, I've used *discursive* by itself, but not to describe a class of writing.  It was used quite extensively in writing on/about post-structuralist theory.  But I'd worry that the polysemy of *discursive* would be confusing. Does it mean related to discourse, or "wandering" or "desultory", etc.? It's also used in some English Buddhist texts to describe the 'everyday' state of mind one wants to get away from in a concentrated meditative state. (But +1 -- it is a good one.)

Comment: @jgbelacqua: For what it's worth, searching for [discursive writing](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1147&bih=822&q="discursive+writing"&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&fp=9a090e7adfed39f) reveals it is commonly used with the "essay" meaning...

Comment: ... and I think that frequency of use probably is a good yardstick for generalized ambiguity or lack thereof?  It does, as you point out, have the sense of being discourse-related, which is right on (though not exclusively so).

Answer (score 6):

I've seen *[expository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expository_writing)* writing.

Comment: It does somewhat depend which particular types of essay one is thinking of. *Didactic* often fits the bill, but it has moralistic overtones not present in *expository*.

Answer (score 2):

The word here is *academic* writing.

Comment: I've added a couple of examples of writing that seem like essays, but that might not be best described as academic writing.

Comment: In that case you might mean "scholarly" writing.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard it described simply as **long-form writing**.